# Scheme: Trying to find largest element in two lists

Tags: scheme

I have 3 functions union, largest, and largest_of_two. Union takes two lists and combines them into one (this function has been tested and works). largest is supposed to return the largest element in a given list but only returns #f whether I call it via largest_of_two or on its own. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
(define (union l1 l2) 
    (cond (
        (null? l1) l2) 
        ((cons (car l1) (union (cdr l1) l2)))
    )
)

(define  (largest x a_list)
    (cond
        ((null? a_list) x)
        ((< x (car a_list)) (= x (car a_list)))
        (else (largest x (cdr a_list)))
    )

)

(define (largest_of_two l1 l2)
    (largest (car l1) (cdr (union l1 l2)))
)

(display(largest_of_two '(19 30 13 29 38) '(1 50 5 20 41)))
```

Comment: The mistake is in `((< x (car a-list)) (= x (car a-list)))`, which should probably be `((< x (car a-list)) (largest (car a-list) (cdr a-list)))` instead.

Comment: The "largest element in a given list" suggests one parameter - a list - not two. With that change, this becomes a trivial application of two procedures.

Comment: I would recommend that you get used to the conventional parenthesis placement. Your method suggests a block structure that doesn't exist. (I personally had massive problems with Lisps until I dropped the "C braces" habit.)

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that `(= x (car a_list))` is a comparison, but you need to make a recursive call here:

```lisp
(define (largest x a_list)
  (cond ((null? a_list) x)
        ((< x (car a_list))  ; if x is less than the first element
         (largest (car a_list) (cdr a_list)))  ; call with first element and cdr
        (else
         (largest x (cdr a_list)))))
```

When `x` is less than the first element of the list, you want to call `largest` again with the first element and a reduced list as arguments.

Yet, calling `largest` with two arguments like this seems awkward. If I want to find the largest element of the list `(1 6 1 8 0 3)` I have to call `(largest 1 '(6 1 8 0 3))`, which is not ideal. A better approach would be to discard the smaller of the first two elements on each iteration until there is only one element left:

```lisp
(define (largest xs)
  (cond ((null? xs) #f)  ; empty input: no largest member
        ((null? (cdr xs))  ; only one member
         (car xs))
        ((> (car xs) (cadr xs))  ; first member is larger than the second
         (largest (cons (car xs) (cddr xs))))  ; keep the first member
        (else
         (largest (cdr xs)))))  ; discard the first member
```

It doesn't make sense to return a numeric result when the input list is empty, so `#f`is returned in that case. If the input list contains only a single value, then that value is returned (note that this code does not verify that a list of one element contains a number, so `(largest '(z))` --> `z`).

Otherwise the list contains at least two values. If the first is larger than the second, the first is consed onto the rest of the list with the second removed (`(cddr xs)`) and `largest` is called again on the result. Otherwise the first value is not larger than the second, so the first element is discarded (`(cdr xs)`) and `largest` is called on that result.

There is another minor issue with the posted definition of `union` in the conditional form:

```lisp
((cons (car l1) (union (cdr l1) l2)))
```

There is only one test expression here. Now, this is legal Scheme because when a selected conditional clause contains only a test expression, the value of the test expression is returned. But this is not idiomatic, and it is hard to read. The posted definition for `largest` used `else` in a similar situation, and it should be used here, too. Or, just use an `if` form:

```lisp
(define (union xs ys)
  (if (null? xs)
      ys
      (cons (car xs) (union (cdr xs) ys))))
```

Be consistent; use formatting and line breaks to make code clear. And while we are talking about style, please don't scatter parentheses about haphazardly, and prefer `kebab-case` (aka `lisp-case`) to `snake_case` for identifiers in lisps.

With the new definition for `largest`, `largest-of-two` has a simpler definition:

```lisp
(define (largest-of-two xs ys)
  (largest (union xs ys)))
```

```
> (largest-of-two '(1 4 2 6 3 11 6 -2) '(3 8 -3 7 10 4))
11
```

Answer (score -1):

Filtering is often called `reduce` in Scheme and functional languages. It is already [explained in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242546/defining-reduce-on-a-list-in-scheme). I quote the implementation:

```lisp
(define (reduce fn list init)
  (if (null? list) init
      (fn (car list)
          (reduce fn (cdr list) init))))
```

This is a very general function, which takes the operation, the list to operate on and an accumulator, which holds the value of each step.

You just need to implement your maximum function for two arguments.

```
(define (max a b)
  (if (> a b)
      a
      b))
```

And then you can pass it to `reduce`. You just need to add an initial value.

```
(reduce max '(19 30 13 29 38) 0)
```

In your case it might be better to split your input list, because all elements can be negative.

```
(let ((lst '(19 30 13 29 38)))
  (reduce max (cdr lst) (car lst)))
```

If you want to do anything twice or for even more arguments, just use `map`.

```
(map (lambda (lst)
       (reduce max (cdr lst) (car lst)))
     '((19 30 13 29 38)
       (1 50 5 20 41)))
```

The following puts everything in one function.

```
(define (largest-of . lists)
  (define (reduce fn list init)
    (if (null? list) init
        (fn (car list)
            (reduce fn (cdr list) init))))
  (define (max a b)
    (if (> a b)
        a
        b))
  (map (lambda (lst)
         (reduce max (cdr lst) (car lst)))
       lists))

(largest-of '(19 30 13 29 38) '(1 50 5 20 41)) ;; => (38 50)
```

This works also for more than two lists. It is just limited by the maximum number of arguments of your Scheme implementation.

And it works for just one argument.

```
(largest-of (largest-of '(19 30 13 29 38) '(1 50 5 20 41))) ;; => (50)
```

You just need to unbox the value with `car`.